# JavaScript startsWith and endsWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form with 2 option elements. When the user hits the "Show Results" button, it will hide the certain table rows based on the month and/or year that was inputted. So for example, November and 2014 were the selected options and the button was clicked, it should show rows whose string matches it and hides those that didn't fit the criteria. I tried something like putting all td rows with ids of each month but that is very redundant because the list would grow. I also tried startsWith() and endsWith() for month and year, respectively.

```
        $("figure.col-sm-3").each(function () {
            var getMonth = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tr')[3].getElementsByTagName('td').startsWith("November");
            $("figure.col-sm-3").hide;
            $(getMonth).show;
            )
        });

<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- FORM AREA -->
        <p>Show items by:</p>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMonth" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Month</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputMonth">
                        <option value="none"> - </option>
                        <option value="January">January</option>
                        <option value="February">February</option>
                        <option value="March">March</option>
                        <option value="April">April</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="June">June</option>
                        <option value="July">July</option>
                        <option value="August">August</option>
                        <option value="September">September</option>
                        <option value="October">October</option>
                        <option value="November">November</option>
                        <option value="December">December</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputYear" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Year</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputYear">
                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Show results</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- FIRST SET OF ITEMS -->
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 1</h6>
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>November 7, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 2</h6>
            <img src="img2.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>December 2, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase"Item 3</h6>
            <img src="img3.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>L</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 4</h6>
            <img src="img4.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>XL</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code. It does not really do `startsWith` or `endsWith`, but I don't see how that is necessary: a date will only have one year in it, and one month. There is no confusion between the two, so just the mere presence of "November" means it is a match. Requiring that "November" appears at the start seems overkill. The same goes for the year.

So, with that in mind, using jQuery's `:contains` will do it:

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    var month = $('#inputMonth').val();
    if (month == 'none') month = '';
    var year = $('#inputYear').val();
    $('div.row').show(); // show all "rows"
    $('figure.col-sm-3')
        .hide() // hide all of them, and then show if both `has` are true
        .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + year + ')')
        .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + month + ')')
        .show();
    // hide any rows that have no more visible figures
    $('div.row:has(figure):not(:has(figure:visible))').hide();
    return false; // to avoid that button submits the form
});
```

```js
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
  var month = $('#inputMonth').val();
  if (month == 'none') month = '';
  var year = $('#inputYear').val();
  $('div.row').show(); // show all "rows"
  $('figure.col-sm-3')
  .hide() // hide all of them, and then show if both `has` are true
  .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + year + ')')
  .has('tr:last-child>td:last-child:contains(' + month + ')')
  .show();
  // hide any rows that have no more visible figures
  $('div.row:has(figure):not(:has(figure:visible))').hide();
  return false; // to avoid that button submits the form
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- FORM AREA -->
        <p>Show items by:</p>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMonth" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Month</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputMonth">
                        <option value="none"> - </option>
                        <option value="January">January</option>
                        <option value="February">February</option>
                        <option value="March">March</option>
                        <option value="April">April</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="June">June</option>
                        <option value="July">July</option>
                        <option value="August">August</option>
                        <option value="September">September</option>
                        <option value="October">October</option>
                        <option value="November">November</option>
                        <option value="December">December</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputYear" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Year</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputYear">
                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Show results</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- FIRST SET OF ITEMS -->
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 1</h6>
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>November 7, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 2</h6>
            <img src="img2.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>36</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>December 2, 2014</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase"Item 3</h6>
            <img src="img3.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>L</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3 thumbnail">
            <h6 class="text-center text-uppercase">Item 4</h6>
            <img src="img4.jpg" />
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="price">
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>new</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>XL</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sold on</td>
                        <td>February 19, 2015</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ahh. So .val is a method in jQuery similar to JS' .value method?

Comment: Indeed, jQuery accesses the `.value` property when you do `.val()`.

Comment: So the option's value is used here. Hmm, what if I get the text of the option? Instead of having <option value="November">November</option>, it would be <option>November</option>. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, but then you need to go to the `option` itself, which is not difficult: `$("#inputMonth option:selected").text();`

Comment: Oh right! I totally forgot about the selector. Thanks. Last, is it possible to move the items up? I have multiple <div class="row">. The code snippet hides items from 1 particular row and it leaves gaps on other rows. Is there a way to sort it?

Comment: Sorry I seem to have missed your last comment. If you have multiple `<div class="row">`, then it could happen that one of them has no more visible elements. If I understand well, in case you want to hide that `div` as well, so it does not appear as a gap. I have updated my answer to achieve that. If it is OK for you, could you accept the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("figure.col-sm-3").each(function () {
  var $months = $('table tr:nth-child(3)')
                .find('td:not(:contains("November"))')
                .closest('tr').hide();
 });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do I do the same for the year?

Comment: I liked @trincot 's solution more